# Strange java number generation

Tags: java, primes

I am trying to create a program that generates all multiples of prime numbers in a given range. However, I encounter a program for large numbers.

```
boolean[] array = new boolean[25000];
for(int k = 2; k <= n; k++){
      if(isPrime(k)){
        //int p = k;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
          if(i*k <= n){
            System.out.println("k: "+k+" i: "+i + " k*i: " + (i*k ));
            array[i*k] ^= true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This code generates and prints all multiples of prime numbers in given range by the user. In my test I am using n = 25000

```
protected boolean isPrime(int number){
    if (number == 2 || number == 3) return true;
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (number%2==0) return false;
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for(int i=3;i*i<=number;i+=2) {
        if(number%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

This is my function that checks if a number is a prime.

Here is a short output of the last few lines when n = 25000

```
k: 2153 i: 3 k*i: 6459
k: 2153 i: 4 k*i: 8612
k: 2153 i: 5 k*i: 10765
k: 2153 i: 6 k*i: 12918
k: 2153 i: 7 k*i: 15071
k: 2153 i: 8 k*i: 17224
k: 2153 i: 9 k*i: 19377
k: 2153 i: 10 k*i: 21530
k: 2153 i: 11 k*i: 23683
k: 2153 i: 997438 k*i: -2147483282
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483282
```

I cannot find a solution (or the code that makes it bug) on the last generation. After k = 2153 and i = 11, the next number is k=2153(that is fine) but i jumps to 997438. I can't find what is making it go that high. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: `k*i` overflows

Comment: I get that but I do not understand why i jumps from 11 to 997438 instead of 12

Comment: @JDoe because when `i=12` and `k=2153`, `i*k=25836` which is greater than `n`. So you're actually skipping `i=12` and so on, until you overflow and `i*k` becomes negative.

Comment: byte b = 127; b = (byte)(b + 1); System.out.println( b ); See how it jumps to negative. Same with large numbers.